# How to find the focal distance of a Lens given its Magnification?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I came across this problem in my physics class, but I don´t how to solve it. The problem is:

> A magnifying glass is used to produce a 4x magnification image. What is the focal distance of its lens?

I know the answer is $+6,25\,$cm, but I don´t know how to solve it.

I´ve tried using the lens formula $\,1/f = 1/d + 1/d_0\ $ and combining it with the magnification formula $M = -d_0/d$, but it did not work.

Comment: You are missing some piece of information here. Magnification tells you by how much things change, but you still need a value that will be changing. You need a distance of some sort. Draw a diagram. object --- Lens --- eye. What are the distances between these three objects?

Comment: This is also my conclusion. But the exercise does not give me any other information.  It is a multiple choice question. Could you answer this question given the following alternatives? a) -6.25 cm, b)+4 cm, c) -4 cm, d)+6.25cm

Comment: I know the focus point must be positive, for a diverging lens would not produce magnification. But is there a way to exclude the +4 cm answer?

Comment: No. As long as the object's distance is 3/4 the focal length, you will get a magnification of 4x. So, 3cm from the 4cm lens and 4.7cm from the 6.25cm lens will both produce the same magnification.

Comment: Yes, I got to the exact same conclusion. I think this question does not make sense. Thanks for the help, anyway!

Comment: This should help: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnifying_glass#Magnification>.